# Jquery Caching issue?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php function that called admin_head() which basically includes the css and jquery files.

```
function admin_head()
{

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>FreshPowder</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="includes/style/fp-admin-style.css" />
        <script src="includes/js/nicEdit/nicEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="includes/js/tagTo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="includes/js/fp_admin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

}
```

I call it at the top of files and everything displays how it should. The only problem is that jquery works on the index.php file, but when you click on a link to say 2.php jquery doesn't work. The two files are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

[How to stop caching with jQuery and javascript](http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-stop-caching-jquery-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks i gave it a shot but it didn't make any difference